# dnf short command disappear in dnf4

Tags: fedora, dnf

After dnf 2.6.2, there're short command abbreviation available. But in recent updates such short commands disappeared (I'm not sure which update, but ever since I upgraded to Fedora 29, those short commands vanished).

Does anyone know how this happened? And if by any chance it's due to my misconfiguration, can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What "short command abbreviation" are you referring to? I've never heard of these things.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i.e. if you want `dnf install` you can use `dnf in` for short, this reference https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Using_DNF#Short_command_variants_of_common_commands provides more details if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

Dnf removed the abbreviations in this [commit](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/commit/359f95a4f4e2390641deb88ab3464239e0f76b4b). They suggest using bash completions to make using dnf faster.